# prototype: return either array or scalar

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, return-value, perl-data-structures

I am having trouble understanding how to return an array using a subroutine prototype.
Here's an example

```
sub f (&@) {
        my ($func) = @_;        
        eval &$func;
}

my $a = f {return 1};
my @b = f {return (2,1,1,4)};

print "a = ".$a."\n";
print "b = ".scalar(@b)."\n";
```

This outputs `a = 1` and `b = 1`, but I expect `@b` to have length four.

I also tried to return the reference `\ eval &$func` in function `f`. I can then dereference the scalar (`$$a` is 1) , but when dereferencing the array (`@$b`) perl tells me that it is not an array reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prototypes have no effect on whether a subroutine returns a scalar or a list. Use [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) if you want to know in what context a subroutine was called.

```
eval &$func;
```

The line above first calls the subroutine referred to by `$func`, in scalar context, then converts its return value into a string and executes that string as a Perl program.

```
sub f (&) {
    my ($func) = @_;
    eval { &$func }
}
```

This will do what you apparently want (call the subroutine referenced by `$func`, in the same context (scalar or list) in which `f` itself was called, within an `eval` block to catch runtime errors).

```
sub f (&) {
    my ($func) = @_;
    eval { $func->(@_) }
}
```

This is more modern style, with the `->` operator.

Comment: One key point that you might want to add is that `eval &$func` will call `$func` in **scalar context** (which is why it's returning just "4"), while `eval { $func->() }` will inherit list or scalar context from the function call to `f()`, so should work as expected.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that `$func` is treated in scalar context! Now it makes sense.

Comment: It's simple: `eval` expects a string for an argument, so it evaluates its operand in scalar context.

Comment: While `&$func()` and `$func->()` are equivalent, `&$func` is different – it will call the function with the current `@_` as arguments. So `f { say "@_" } 1, 2, 3` would print out `CODE(0x0123ABCD) 1 2 3`.

Comment: @amon I never knew that!

Answer (score 1):

No need to eval, you can

```
use warnings;
sub f (&) {
    my ($func) = @_;
    $func->(); # better than &$func
}
```

`eval` on the other hand returns only last element in the list given by `$f` as it is a same thing as writing `eval scalar $func->();`, so `@b` ends up with one element => `4`

From [perldoc -f eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)

> the return value of EXPR is parsed and executed as if it were a little Perl program. The value of the expression (which is itself determined within scalar context) is first parsed, and if there were no errors, executed as a block within the lexical context of the current Perl program.